# NotImplementedError apache beam python

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm writing a json to gcs using apache beam. But encountered the following error

`NotImplementedError: offset: 0, whence: 0, position: 50547, last: 50547 [while running 'Writing new data to gcs/write data gcs/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles']`

Don't know why this error is occurring. Code for the same is as follows:

```
class WriteDataGCS(beam.PTransform):
        """
        To write data to GCS
        """

        def __init__(self, bucket):
            """
            Initiate the bucket as a class field

            :type bucket:string
            :param bucket: query to be run for data
            """
            self.bucket = bucket

        def expand(self, pcoll):
            """
            PTransform Method run when called on Class Name

            :type pcoll: PCollection
            :param pcoll: A pcollection
            """
            (pcoll | "print intermediate" >> beam.Map(print_row))
            return (pcoll | "write data gcs" >> beam.io.WriteToText(self.bucket, coder=JsonCoder(), file_name_suffix=".json"))
```

```
class JsonCoder:
    """
    This class represents dump and load operations performed on json
    """
    def encode(self,data):
        """
        Encodes the json data.

        :type data: string
        :param data: Data to be encoded
        """
        # logger.info("JSON DATA for encoding - {}".format(data))
        return json.dumps(data,default=str)

    def decode(self,data):
        """
        Decodes the json data.

        :type data: string
        :param data: Data to be decoded
        """
        # logger.info("JSON DATA for decoding - {}".format(data))
        return json.loads(data)
```

Comment: user@beam.apache.com might be the better place for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `coder` argument of `WriteToText` expects an `apache_beam.coders.Coder` instance. You could try making your `JsonCoder` inherit from the base `Coder` class, but I think you can also convert your data to a string using a `Map`:

```py
        def expand(self, pcoll):
            """
            PTransform Method run when called on Class Name

            :type pcoll: PCollection
            :param pcoll: A pcollection
            """
            return (pcoll
              | "print intermediate" >> beam.Map(print_row))
              | "to_json" >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.dumps(x, default=str)))
              | "write data gcs" >> beam.io.WriteToText(self.bucket, file_name_suffix=".json"))
```